# Configuring winform app to call SOAP https with windows autentication

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, soap, service-reference

I have a SOAP that I'm trying to work with but I encounter the next problem that I didn't find the solution in similar questions:
The SOAP has to be called via HTTPS and with Windows credentials.

What I tried to do in the app config is the next things:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceSoap">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://someapp/SDK/WebService.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap"
        contract="someapp_contract.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the error that I get is:

```
The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.And the error
```

I tried a differt confingruation too with **basicHttpBinding**
and

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
```

But than the error that is I get is(which is a very logical error):

```
provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'...
```

Did anyone have the same issue in the past?

Thanks in advance.
Max

P.S:
If I do

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

instead of

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
```

I get the next error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the settings above.
When I use:

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

and get the error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
```

What I did are the next changes.
1) first at the app.config

```
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Than at the code:

```
public static class Ssl
{
    private static readonly string[] TrustedHosts = new[] {
      "YourServiceName", 
      "YourServiceName2"
    };

    public static void EnableTrustedHosts()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var request = sender as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                return TrustedHosts.Contains(request.RequestUri.Host);
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
}
```

And:

```
YourContractInstance.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = ***;
YourContractInstance.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = ***;
YourContractInstance.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = ***;
YourContractInstance.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
```

All of this workaround was made because I have some problem with the certificate|DNS configuration on the host of the SOAP service that I'm not allowed to access so I had to add the Service reference by IP.